# parseJson is running into an unexpected error (Unexpected identifier)

Tags: php, jquery

This is all in the same script. I know the difference between ajax and serverside code. I have php interwoven in this javascript script as follows:

```
<script>
    <?php
        $json_string = json_encode(array("agent_table" => "<span style='float: left;'></span>"));
    ?>

    var response = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $json_string; ?>');
</script>
```

But `parseJson` is complaining of an error. The error disappears when I remove the styling from the `span`.

The error is 'Unexpected identifier'. This is in Chrome.

Comment: whats the error? Try putting the value in double quotes. Does that produce anything different?

Comment: Please mention error here. Also, i dont understand why have you kept $json_string inside script tag. It can be placed outside too.

Comment: What *exactly* does the code look like when it makes it to the browser? (Like when you do "view source".)

Comment: @Pointy how would I find that out? Btw this is part of a large javascript web app I have custom built.

Comment: i think, its the matter of special characters. Check the source-code using firebug or something like that. Check what is there exactly inside parseJSON.

Comment: $.parseJSON('{"agent_table":"<span style='float: left;'><\/span>"}');

Comment: Actually BattleBit has the right idea in his/her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `'` characters in your data. These will continue to be represented as literal `'` characters in the JSON.

You are embedding your JSON directly into a JavaScript string, and that string is delimited by `'` characters. The first `'` that appears *as data* in the JSON will terminate the JS string.

This is a general problem when embedding on data format in another. You are embedding JSON in JavaScript in HTML.

Your options:

- Replace every instance of `'` in the JSON with `\'` (so they mean "Apostrophe"  instead of "End of JS string")
- Treat the JSON as a JavaScript object literal instead of trying to munge it into a string which you run it through a JSON parser.

The latter option is the sane one (so long as your goal doesn't involve proving that PHP can generate valid JSON).

```
var response = <?php echo $json_string; ?>;
```

You don't need to worry about further escaping for inserting into the HTML because the only sequence you need to worry about (inside a script element) is `</script>` and PHP's `json_encode` will output `<\/script>` for that anyway.

Comment: THanks for your effort Quentin. But replacing every instance of ' with \' still gives the same error. Here is the string as it reaches the browser: '{"agent_table":"<span style=\\'float left\\'><\/span>"}'; Note it adds an extra back slash to each of \'  . Btw Treating the JSON as a Javascript object literal would involve rewriting a chunk of code and retesting it.

Comment: Replacing with `\'` should fix it. I can't tell why your (new, unshared) code is double escaping it (but double escaping would be expected to break it).

Comment: If I place no backslashes I get unexpected identifier and if I place  \' the browser turns it into \\' and I get unexpected identifier. No new unshared code, it's all in the original question.

Comment: @Hardworker — It sounds like you are escaping the `'` in the raw data and then transforming it to JSON. That isn't what I said. You need to replace the `'` in the JSON (i.e. *after* you have run `json_encode` over the raw data).

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I realised that just after I typed my last response. Thanks for all the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

May be it?

```
<script>
<?php
$json_string = json_encode(array(
                               "agent_table"=> '<span style="float: left;"></span>'
                           ));
?>
var response = <?php echo $json_string;?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes this is true; there's no need for `$.parseJSON()` at all :-) However if the JSON is messed up there'll still be an error.

Comment: I actually do need parseJSON. I have trimmed down the code considerably for this question. I will try putting the string into a response var first though

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately gives the same error. Btw there have to be quotes around those php tags.

Comment: @Hardworker — How can that give the same error? You said the error was being raised from `parseJSON`, the game of spot-the-difference here removes it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

try it!!!

```
<script>
<?php
$json_string = json_encode(array('agent_table' => addslashes('<span style="float: left;"></span>')));
?>

var response = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $json_string; ?>');
```

Comment: Try what? Please don't answer questions with spot-the-difference games.

Comment: Thanks but it still gives the same error (unexpected identifier) Here is the string as it reaches the browser: '{"agent_table":"<span style=\\'float left\\'><\/span>"}'; Note it adds an extra back slash to each of \' .